# Is Parashara the original author of Vishnu Purana?

Tags: vyasa, vishnu-purana, parashara

https://www.quora.com/It-is-believed-that-Veda-Vyasa-was-the-author-of-all-the-Puranas-However-is-this-actually-true-As-there-were-most-likely-lots-of-sages-who-authored-these-teachings/answer/Rami-Sivan

One of the claims made in the above Quora answer is:

> Vyāsa did not in fact compose all the Purāṇas — the oldest and the most authentic of the Puranas — **the Vishnu Purāṇa was narrated by Parāśara** — the alleged father of Vyāsa. (**It is claimed that Vyāsa later redacted and rearranged it**).

Is there anything in Hindu scriptures or scholarly works (research papers, publications, journals, etc.) that supports this claim?

Answer (score 2):

Parasara got a boon from Pulastya and his grandfather Vasishta that he will be auther of Vishnu Purana. In [Vishnu Purana: Book 1: Chapter 1](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp035.htm), Parasar tells the story how got this boon before narrating the Vishnu Purana to sages.

> Paráśara replied, ...
> Then arrived Pulastya, the son of Brahmá, who was received by my grandfather with the customary marks of respect. The illustrious brother of Pulaha said to me; Since, in the violence of animosity, you have listened to the words of your progenitor, and have exercised clemency, therefore you shall become learned in every science: since you have forborne, even though incensed, to destroy my posterity, I will bestow upon you another **boon**, and, you shall become the **author** of a summary of the Puráńas; you shall know the true nature of the deities, as it really is; and, whether engaged in religious rites, or abstaining from their performance, your understanding, through my favour, shall be perfect, and exempt from doubts. Then my grandsire Vaśisht́ha added; Whatever has been said to thee by Pulastya, shall assuredly come to pass.

Comment: So what was Vyasa's role/contribution in this Purana?

Comment: Rearranging....